# Json.Net NuGet (NuPack) Package Reference unable to find assembly compatible with target framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, json.net, nuget

I am getting an error when trying to add the Json.net package reference through the NuGet / NuPack Add Package Reference Dialog.  The error I get is:

> Unable to find assembly references that are compatible with the target framework 'Silverlight,Version=4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone'

I have the latest version of both the Windows Phone 7 SDK and the Package Manager tools installed.  This is running in Visual Studio 2010.

Has anyone else run into this error?

Comment: for what it's worth, I went into the package console and got the TargetFrameworkMoniker for my project I'm trying to add the reference too, and it does match the target framework. $p.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value
Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone

Answer (score 1):

According to James Newton-King (author of Json.NET), you can use the Silverlight 3.0 version.

http://json.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=226910

Unfortunately the NuGet package doesn't properly indicate Windows Phone 7 support. So you'll have to add the reference the old-fashioned way. (e.g. Copy the assembly into a directory such as ~\lib\Json.NET - where ~ is your solution root - and Project... Add Reference...)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the old fashioned way is not useful in this situation.  I myself am trying to create a NuGet package that depends on Json.Net, so it defeats the purpose if I manually add the reference.  I may start looking into modifying the Json.net NuGet package and submitting a patch to json.codeplex.com

Comment: I agree. Your only choice is to update the Json.NET NuGet package so that it is compatible with Windows Phone 7. :)